# Angularjs: Call bootstrap modal multiple views.

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, scope, view

My goal is to move the modal out of my source view, and move it into its own view, but for some reason, my modal does not show up. I have tried putting the modal into a directive, but its not working. I have moved the modal to the index page, but then the view changes when they modal opens.

Category.html

```
<section class="row">
    <h1>{{ selectedCategory | uppercase}}</h1>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="source in sources[selectedCategory]">
        <a ng-href="#/explore/{{selectedCategory}}/{{source.name}}">
            <section class="col-xs-2">
                <img ng-src="assets/img/{{source.imagename}}" height="30" width="30">
            </section>
            <p class="col-xs-8">{{ source.name }}</p>
        </a>

        <div ng-if="!objectContains(addedSources,source.name)"><!-- Show this, if addesSources does not contains source.name -->
            <section class="col-xs-2">
                <!-- This part, is where i want the modal to be called. -->
                <button class="tiny" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="setUpModalData(source.name)">Add</button> 
            </section>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="objectContains(addedSources,source.name)"> <!-- Show this, if addesSources contains source.name -->
            <section class="col-xs-2">
                <button class="tiny secondary" ng-click="removeSource(source.name)">remove</button>
            </section> 
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal content -->
        </div><!-- modal-content -->
    </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- myModal -->
```

Currently the controller does not open or close the modal, its only job is to provide the information shown in the modal. If you click on add for a particular source, the modal will open with that source name on the top.

I have tried doing what seems to work for other people, but i cant get it to work for me.

I want to be able to call this modal from different views. You can click add on the source List view (list of all sources), and the individual source view(details about one source). There will be an add button on both views, that will both call this modal.

I am using twitter bootstrap for the css.

Here is my Controller for this view.

```
.controller('CategoryController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
$http.get('assets/js/Category.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.selectedCategory = $routeParams.simplename; //Get the the name of the url
    $scope.sources = data; //set sources list, for view to iterate.

    $scope.collectionList = {}; // List of all collections, and source under every collection
    $scope.addedSources = {}; // object of sources, and the collection they're in. etc ("The Verge" : tech)

    $scope.setUpModalData = function(simplename){
        $scope.selectedSourceName = $scope.selectedSourceNameTitle =simplename; 
        $scope.selectedCollection = $scope.selectedCategory;

        /* if the current category does not exist in the collection list,
        *  we will pre fill the form with the current category.
        *  Other wise we will set it, and it will not be pre pubulated.
        */
        if(!($scope.selectedCategory in $scope.collectionList)){
            $scope.collectionName = $scope.selectedCategory;
            $scope.selectedCollection = 'createNewCollection';
        }

    }

    $scope.removeSource = function(simplename){
        var collectionNameHolder = $scope.addedSources[simplename]; //The collection the source is in.

        delete $scope.collectionList[collectionNameHolder][simplename]; //delete the source from both lists.
        delete $scope.addedSources[simplename]
    }

    $scope.arrayContains = function(array, element){
        return (array.indexOf(element) > -1);
    }

    $scope.objectContains = function(object, element){
        return (element in object);
    }
});
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put that in a simplified jsfiddle? I'm not sure about what you're trying to achieve and what's not working.

In any case, if you want to have a single modal for multiple views, you could do that with a service, which job would be to open or close the modal, or with events on rootScope which would tell the modal's controller that the modal should be displayed or hidden.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast